# Reaction time game

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm working on a small Facebook game where users can test their reaction speed.

Basically the users joins the game, after a random amount of time a light changes color and the user has to click as fast as possible.

Since the game is entirely javascript based, I'm worried that "smart" users just would be able to alter the javascript and use it in their advantage.

Would there be a way to prevent this? How could I stop people from messing with the javascript and giving themselves impossible scores?

Comment: You can't do much against a gebugging console, but you can protect from scriptlets. I'm thinking about some kind of authentication token generated by the client and not stored in the global scope.

Comment: If you seek protection from the debugging console, you'll probably have to reach for another options (Flash/Java) :-(

Answer (score 2):

Well since JavaScript complies in the browser there is always a way for the user to alter the code to their benefit. You could complicate things greatly by using Google closure compiler to minify your code. Also, add all your methods to a function closure to make access to your methods harder from the console, something like this

```
(function(window){....}());
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm certainly gonna look into closures as a start.